Question about proof of theorem regarding Galois Extensions and Intermediate Fields
In a proof in my textbook, one step of the proof reads " by the proof of Lemma 54, every injective map $υ:B\rightarrow E$ fixing $F$ (here, $F \subset B \subset E$ are all fields) must permute the roots of f(x) (we are assuming $B$ is the splitting field of f(x)).
Lemma 54 is the proof that automorphisms in the Galois group of an extension field permute the roots of a polynomial f(x). The proof is just applying σ to some $f(x) \in F[x]$ but the proof relies heavily on the fact that σ is an isomorphism.
In particular, the proof goes: (here α is a root)
$σ(f(α)) = σ(c_0+c_1α+...+c_nα^n)$
$= σ(c_0)+ σ(c_1)σ(α)+...+σ(c_n)σ(α)^n $
$=c_0 +c_1α+...+c_nσ(α)^n = 0$.
This proof clearly uses the fact that σ is an isomorphism to split up sums and products to show that σ permutes the roots. So why should this be true of any injective map?
Thanks in advance!

This is assumed to be a field homomorphism. Read "map" as "homomorphism" throughout. Arbitrary functions aren't really considered in this setting.

Ah ok thank you !!
